# Why list comprehension can be faster than map() in Python?

Tags: python, performance, list-comprehension, interpreter

I am looking in to the performance issues of the loop like structures in Python and found the following statements:

> Besides the syntactic benefit of list comprehensions, they are often
>   as fast or faster than equivalent use of map.
>   ([Performance Tips](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips))
>
> List comprehensions run a bit faster than equivalent for-loops (unless
>   you're just going to throw away the result).
>   ([Python Speed](https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed))

I am wondering what difference under the hood gives list comprehension this advantage. Thanks.

Comment: http://blog.codinghorror.com/learn-to-read-the-source-luke/

Comment: Hmm, I've always used list comprehensions even if I completely throw away the result...

Comment: @JohnColeman: :/ please do that and post an answer...

Comment: try comparing using `dis`

Comment: @KarolyHorvath I'm not the one who is curious -- but I would think that if you are curious about what's under a hood it can't hurt to lift it up and look, even if you have to later consult with an expert mechanic to interpret what you see.

Comment: Did you look at _any_ of the related questions? Like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1247486/python-list-comprehension-vs-map)?

Comment: @JohnColeman You mean the source of the python interpreter?

Comment: @JamesLu Good practice :)

Comment: @Bin -- yes. Why not? Good programmers wrote it, Any effort in trying to wrap your head around some of it will pay off sooner or later. I'm far from an expert on it but feel that I learned a fair amount just reading up on the Python/C API (which allows you to write C code which interacts with some of the Python internals).

Comment: @JohnColeman So the Python/C API is the resource containing the details. Thanks for pointing me to this resource.

Comment: @JeffMercado Thanks for pointing to this post. It have a lot of very useful use cases. I got more understanding on how different scenarios play out in practice.

Comment: @Bin -- The C API contains *some* of the details but it isn't the source itself but, for example, provides details about how Python objects are represented in memory.

Comment: @Bin Just tested it, it actually runs 33% slower. Guess I didn't need all that extra complexity.

Comment: @JohnColeman My response: "OH NO!! All that C code is melting my Python eyes! I have a time limit and don't know C!!!"

Comment: I am going to try @scorreia 's method and compare the machine code.

Comment: @JamesLu Definitely check it out, it can only help. Plus it is almost literally what is happening "under the hood"

Comment: @scorreia I'm writing code to compare the diffs right now.

Comment: My answer is more about for loops, but `map()` uses a python for loop so it's pretty much the same.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Test one**: throwing away the result.

Here's our dummy function:

```
def examplefunc(x):
    pass
```

And here are our challengers:

```
def listcomp_throwaway():
    [examplefunc(i) for i in range(100)]

def forloop_throwaway():
    for i in range(100):
        examplefunc(i)
```

I won't do an analysis of its raw speed, only *why*, per the OP's question. Lets take a look at the diffs of the machine code.

```
--- List comprehension
+++ For loop
@@ -1,15 +1,16 @@
- 55           0 BUILD_LIST               0
+ 59           0 SETUP_LOOP              30 (to 33)
               3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
               6 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
               9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
              12 GET_ITER            
-        >>   13 FOR_ITER                18 (to 34)
+        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
              16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
-             19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (examplefunc)
+
+ 60          19 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (examplefunc)
              22 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
              25 CALL_FUNCTION            1
-             28 LIST_APPEND              2
-             31 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
-        >>   34 POP_TOP             
-             35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
-             38 RETURN_VALUE        
+             28 POP_TOP             
+             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
+        >>   32 POP_BLOCK           
+        >>   33 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
+             36 RETURN_VALUE
```

The race is on. Listcomp's first move is to build an empty list, while for loop's is to setup a loop. Both of them then proceed to load global range(), the constant 100, and call the range function for a generator. Then they both get the current iterator and get the next item, and store it into the variable i. Then they load examplefunc and i and call examplefunc. Listcomp appends it to the list and starts the loop over again. For loop does the same in three instructions instead of two. Then they both load None and return it.

So who seems better in this analysis? Here, list comprehension does some redundant operations such as building the list and appending to it, if you don't care about the result. For loop is pretty efficient too.

If you time them, using a for loop is about one-third faster than a list comprehension. (In this test, examplefunc divided its argument by five and threw it away instead of doing nothing at all.)

**Test two**: Keeping the result like normal.

No dummy function this test. So here are our challengers:

```
def listcomp_normal():
    l = [i*5 for i in range(100)]


def forloop_normal():
    l = []
    for i in range(100):
        l.append(i*5)
```

The diff isn't any use to us today. It's just the two machine codes in two blocks.

List comp's machine code:

```
 55           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
              6 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
              9 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             12 GET_ITER            
        >>   13 FOR_ITER                16 (to 32)
             16 STORE_FAST               0 (i)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (i)
             22 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             25 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             26 LIST_APPEND              2
             29 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           13
        >>   32 STORE_FAST               1 (l)
             35 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             38 RETURN_VALUE
```

For loop's machine code:

```
 59           0 BUILD_LIST               0
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (l)

 60           6 SETUP_LOOP              37 (to 46)
              9 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (range)
             12 LOAD_CONST               1 (100)
             15 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             18 GET_ITER            
        >>   19 FOR_ITER                23 (to 45)
             22 STORE_FAST               1 (i)

 61          25 LOAD_FAST                0 (l)
             28 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
             31 LOAD_FAST                1 (i)
             34 LOAD_CONST               2 (5)
             37 BINARY_MULTIPLY     
             38 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             41 POP_TOP             
             42 JUMP_ABSOLUTE           19
        >>   45 POP_BLOCK           
        >>   46 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             49 RETURN_VALUE
```

As you can probably already tell, the list comprehension has fewer instructions than for loop does.

List comprehension's checklist:

1. Build an anonymous empty list.
2. Load `range`.
3. Load `100`.
4. Call `range`.
5. Get the iterator.
6. Get the next item on that iterator.
7. Store that item onto `i`.
8. Load `i`.
9. Load the integer five.
10. Multiply times five.
11. Append the list.
12. Repeat steps 6-10 until range is empty.
13. Point `l` to the anonymous empty list.

For loop's checklist:

1. Build an anonymous empty list.
2. Point `l` to the anonymous empty list.
3. Setup a loop.
4. Load `range`.
5. Load `100`.
6. Call `range`.
7. Get the iterator.
8. Get the next item on that iterator.
9. Store that item onto `i`.
10. Load the list `l`.
11. Load the attribute `append` on that list.
12. Load `i`.
13. Load the integer five.
14. Multiply times five.
15. Call `append`.
16. Go to the top.
17. Go to absolute.

(Not including these steps: Load `None`, return it.)

The list comprehension doesn't have to do these things:

- Load append of the list every time, since it's pre-bound as a local variable.
- Load `i` twice per loop
- Spend two instructions going to the top
- Directly append to the list instead of calling a wrapper that appens the list

In conclusion, listcomp is a lot faster if you are going to use the values, but if you don't it's pretty slow.

**Real speeds**

Test one: for loop is faster by about one-third*

Test two: list comprehension is faster by about two-thirds*

*About -> second decimal place acurrate

Comment: @Bin Thanks! I helped myself too, so win-win!